# What does Lightning Debug Mode do exactly?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, debugging

When you enable `UserPreferencesUserDebugModePref` on a [User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm), s/he will be running lightning components in debug mode.

The only difference I could perceive is that (more) console warns are printed. Per [Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_debug_mode.htm) the code should also be minified but I don't see this happening. I am confused.

What does Lightning Debug Mode exactly do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is: I misunderstood the docs plain and simply.

> Optimization and minification are performed on *framework code* only. **Custom component code is NOT minified or obfuscated**.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_debug_mode.htm?search_text=debug
(Above the yellow boxes)

Kudos @DanielBallinger

Comment: Also note that disabling debug mode supresses some common lightning component errors, sort of like production mode in a JavaScript application.